# Tkinter automatically opens my file

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a GUI app where you can open a file and then you can calculate some things on it (from the main function). However, when I run this program, it automatically opens the file which I chose and the main() function runs, even if I haven't commanded it yet. Here is the relevant part of the code for now:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
import tkMessageBox
import math
import re




class App(object):
  def __init__(self, master):
    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()

    self.text = Text()
    self.text.pack()
    menu = Menu(master)
    root.config(menu=menu)

    filemenu = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

    filemenu.add_command(label="Open File", command=self.OpenFile)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Save File As", command=self.SaveFile)

    processmenu = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="Calculate", menu=processmenu)
    processmenu.add_cascade(label="Process the Input File", command = main())

    helpmenu = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu =helpmenu)
    helpmenu.add_command(label="About", command=self.about)


    exitmenu = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="Quit", menu=exitmenu)
    exitmenu.add_command(label="Quit", command=self.quit)

  def about(self):
    tkMessageBox.showinfo( "About", "Lot Data Calculator v.01"\
        "\n Made by Michael Hander."\
         "\n Contact him at http://www.twitter.com/sludgehander."\
         "\n All Rights Reserved. 2015")

  def OpenFile(self):
    infile = tkFileDialog.askopenfile()
    text = infile.read()
    if text != None:
        self.text.delete(0.0, END)
        self.text.insert(END,text)

  def SaveFile(self):
    outputfile = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile()
    savethetext = str(self.text.get(0.0,END))
    outputfile.write(savethetext)
    outputfile.close()

  def quit(self):
    root.destroy()


def main():
  infile = tkFileDialog.askopenfile()
  #algorithms to solve the input file
```

My plan is to open the program and then I can open the file, and then the input shows on the widget below. I have made that, except when I run the program, it doesn't show me the menu and instead an open file dialog shows immediately. And I tried putting the main() in the command of the process menu, but still when I click it, nothing happens. Also, after the main() function is done, I should save it to a new file using the Save File menu but I don't know how to put all of the strings that results.

http://dpaste.com/1BV8YR2 Here is the whole function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this bit of code:

```
processmenu.add_cascade(...,  command = main())
```

You are asking python to run the `main` function, and whatever it returns is what gets assigned to the `command` attribute.

You want to remove the parenthesis so that you are passing a *reference* to the function, rather than the result of executing the function:

```
processmenu.add_cascade(..., command = main)
```

Comment: I have removed the () from the main in command and now the Process menu works! Thanks. The GUI still has so many bugs that I don't know how to fix though